# Create Shedule Task for execute Powershell script immediately using Powershell

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I need create schedule task programmatically using Powershell (PS remoting).

My task executes a powershell script (and other cases a script cmd) immediately.

```
$powershellcmd = (get-command powershell.exe).Definition
$upgradeWSPps1 = (Join-Path $ScriptDirectory Tests.LifeCycle.Deploy.MOSS.UpgradeWSP.ps1)

$cmdToRun = "$powershellcmd -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -NoLogo -File ""$upgradeWSPps1"" "
```

If you're creating a scheduled task by providing $cmdToRun to schtasks then you'll need to use both Windows CLI style escape character and Powershell style escape characters for double-quotes. In Powershell the back-tick ` is the escape character, but in Windows CLI (classic Windows shell) it is the forward slash.

Any suggestions about it ? any good sample code ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a script I use to create a Task which runs a script file. It is *insecure* because if you choose to register the task as a user, than you'll need to provide his/her's password in plain text.

```
function Set-PowerShellScriptTask {
param(
    $Computers,
    $Script,
    $TaskName,
    $Interval = 15,
    $User,
    $Password = "pwd",
    $Root = "Scripts"
)
process {
    $file = get-item $Script -ea Stop
    

    $action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -WorkingDirectory "D:\$Root\$($file.BaseName)"  -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument "-ep Unrestricted -File D:\Scripts\$($file.BaseName)\$($file.name)"

    #from https://xplantefeve.io/posts/SchdTskOnEvent
    $class = Get-Cimclass MSFT_TaskRepetitionPattern Root/Microsoft/Windows/TaskScheduler
    $reps = New-CimInstance -CimClass $class -ClientOnly
    $reps.Interval = "PT$($Interval)M" #15 minutes
    $reps.StopAtDurationEnd = $False
    
    $triggers = @(( New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogon ),(New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At (get-date) -RepetitionInterval (new-timespan -Minutes $Interval) -Once:$False))
    $triggers[0].Repetition = $reps
    #$triggers[0].ExecutionTimeLimit = 'PT30M' #stop if ran for more than 30 minutes
    #$triggers[0].StartBoundary = [string](get-date).AddMinutes(1).toString('O')

    $settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -StartWhenAvailable
    
    $Computers | ForEach-Object {
        robocopy $file.DirectoryName "\\$_\D$\$Root\$($file.BaseName)"
        $sess = New-CimSession $_ -ea Stop
        $act = Get-ScheduledTask -CimSession $sess -TaskName $TaskName
        if($act) {
            Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName $TaskName -ea Stop
        }
        if ($User -match '^NT AUTHORITY\\') {
            Register-ScheduledTask -CimSession $sess -Action $action -Trigger $triggers -Settings $settings -TaskName $TaskName-User $User
        } else {
            Register-ScheduledTask -CimSession $sess -Action $action -Trigger $triggers -Settings $settings -TaskName $TaskName-User $User -Password $Password
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Import-module for use New-ScheduledTaskAction  cmdlet ?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtaskaction?view=win10-ps I think it comes with Windows 10, no need to import the module

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to create a scheduled task on a remote computer to immediately run a script? Just run the script directly on the remote computer.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName COMPUTER -ScriptBlock { COMMAND }
```

Comment: I need it, another issues in my company (permissions in deploy sharepoint, etc). I want testing create scheduled task, I need do it that way.

Comment: The command to create scheduled tasks is [schtasks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: If you're creating a scheduled task by providing $cmdToRun to schtasks then you'll need to use both Windows CLI style escape character and Powershell  style escape characters for double-quotes.
In Powershell the back-tick ` is the escape character, but in Windows CLI (classic Windows shell) it is the forward slash. Any good sample about it?

Comment: The escape character for CMD is the caret `^` (and sometimes the backslash), not the forward slash.